# Sort a collection of values based on another collection in a "Scala way"

Tags: scala, sorting, functional-programming

I have to sort a collection of values depending on a set of keys I have available as sublists of another list.
Currently, I have the following code which does the job properly. However, it uses a mutable collection and I know this is not the best way to do this in Scala. What would be the pretty "Scala way" of doing this ? 
Thanks.

```
var sorted: IndexedSeq[IndexedSeq[Any]]
//sortKeys is a list of lists containing sorting properties (index,descending/ascending) 
for (i <- (0 until sortKeys).reverse) {
      val index = sortKeys(i).get(i).getIndex
      val desc = sortKeys.get(i).descending
      if (desc) {
        sorted = sorted.sorted { (t1: IndexedSeq, t2: IndexedSeq) => -t1(index).asInstanceOf[Comparable[Any]].compareTo(t2(index)) }
      } else {
        sorted = sorted.sorted { (t1: IndexedSeq, t2: IndexedSeq) => t1(index).asInstanceOf[Comparable[Any]].compareTo(t2(index)) }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you write https://scalafiddle.io/ with your implementation. I don't get something. (paste your code with example, ensure it compiles and then `ctrl+s` and share link with us)

Comment: In particular `sorted` will need to have to been initialized to something (presumably the unsorted input)

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to precise I assumed that sorted contains all the unsorted values at the beginning. I simplified the code a bit for readability. This is part of a big class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rough sketch:

```
val sortKeys = Seq( (1,true), (2, false))

val input = Seq( Array("a", "b", "c"), Array("a", "x", "c" )

sortKeys.foldRight(input){
  case ( (index, ascending), acc) =>
     acc.sortWith( (a,b) => if (ascending) a(index) > b(index)    
          else a(index) < b(index))
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I adapted this to my implementation and it worked. I had to use sorted with compare to instead of sortBy because my elements don't have implicit ordering.
I was missing the foldRight... It was the key